# Is there any Magento code to get phtml file path from a particular theme?

Tags: magento, php

Due to some reason I need to access a phtml file from mobile theme.

Is there any direct access code to fulfill the purpose ?

For example -

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml();
```

This code returns the Search Form from Default theme but I need it from mobile theme.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
// Switch to the desired theme
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
->setTheme('mobile?'); // Name of theme

Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml();
```

But we aware that this would switch your theme for the rest of the page rendering... and you might get unexpected results afterwards. You probably should be able to first store your current theme & package and restore if afterwards using:

```
$currentPackage = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName();
$currentTheme = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend');

// Your stuff...

Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend')
->setPackageName($currentPackage)
->setTheme($currentTheme);
```